# Using jQuery Date picker with name instead of id in struts application

Tags: jquery, datepicker, struts

I want to use jquery datepicker plugin in struts .can anyone help me in this regard
i have id for date picker but  i want to populate using name or struts equivalent
i want to populate using name intsead of id .please help me in this regard

```
<input  name="ADate"  id="datepicker" type="text" class="txtBox">
<script> 
    $(function() {

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({                 
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',                     
        });                 
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $( "input[name='ADate']" ).datepicker({                 
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'                     
    });                 
});
```

Did you mean something like that

Comment: Works like a charm. It is indeed useful when developing struts application. Struts generates the ids of html elements which don't always match the names.